# display child records with checkbox on lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, controller

I have a requirement to select child records of selected record on a detail page.
This Lightning component, will be used on Account record page and that Account record's related contact records will be displayed with checkbox to select on the page.

I found this [code](https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/04/30/add-multiple-child-records-lightning-component/) handy to some extent but it displays all the contact records from the org that can be added as child to the selected Account record. In a nutshell, this works in the reverse way of what I am expecting where i need to display already available child contact records with a checkbox to select.

Can anyone please suggest the possible approach w.r.t my requirement above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code in the link has all of the ingredients needed for the solution that you're looking for :)

You could add a parameter to the example getContacts method that receives the Account Id and filter the query by that Id:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Contact> getContacts(Id accountId) {
    List<Contact> totalList = new List<Contact>();
    for(Contact cc : [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId=:accountId]) {
        totalList.add(cc);
    }   
    return totalList;
}
```

Finally, just make sure that the Lightning Component's JS Controller/Helper passes the Record Id to that parameter in the Action:

```
var action = component.get('c.getContacts');

action.setParams({
    "accountId": component.get("v.recordId")
});

action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
    var state = actionResult.getState();
    if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
        //set response value in ChildRecordList attribute on component.
        component.set('v.ChildRecordList', actionResult.getReturnValue());
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Comment: while trying your suggested code, I am getting the following error: "Failed to save RelatedListController.js: c.RelatedList: Failed to parse CONTROLLER for js://c.ChildList: org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException: Expected ':' [27, 9]: 'action': Source"

Please suggest

Comment: Could you possibly add a snippet of your RelatedListController.js controller code? Particularly line 27, where the error is happening?